# question on the size of Bernoulli sample in aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, sample-data

I am getting a 1% Bernoulli random sample from an athena table. However, the size of the sample table returned is only 0.4% of the original table. Both are in parquet format. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Then Bernoulli option will select rows with the given probability, only on average will you get the given percentage of output rows but any individual query will have a varying number of rows. As a rule of thumb, if your table has `N` rows, you can expect the output table to have a number of rows between `N +/- sqrt(N)`